# Как узнать что процесс приложения убит юзером, а не системой?

Tags: android

Приложение может убить юзером и системой. Как узнать что послужило причиной уничтожения процесса?

Comment: вы это хотите в какой момент узнать? ну то есть после уничтожения процесса это вряд ли будет возможно, до - тоже не очень понятен момент когда приложение прибьют

Comment: хочу узнать перед уничтожением процесса

Comment: Убить юзер может только одним способом, через exit. Вот и смотрите на нажатие клавиши выход

Comment: а как же уничтожение процесса в менеджере приложений? взмахом вверх или вбок?